# AutoMapper - Nested Collections Not Getting Mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have an ASP.NET Core application with the following entity classes:

```
public class CustomerEntity : IAuditableEntity {
   private readonly List<AddressEntity> _addresses = new List<AddressEntity>();

   public CustomerEntity() {
      Id = default;
      IsPremierCustomer = false;
   }

   public int Id { get; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }

   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

   public bool IsPremierCustomer { get; private set; }

   public CustomerTypeEntity CustomerType { get; }

   public IReadOnlyCollection<AddressEntity> Addresses => _addresses;

   public void AddAddress(AddressEntity address) {
      _addresses.Add(address);
   }

   public void SetPremierStatus(bool premierCustomer) {
      if (IsPremierCustomer == premierCustomer) {
         return;
      }

      IsPremierCustomer = premierCustomer;
   }
}

public class CustomerTypeEntity {
   public CustomerTypeEntity(string description) {
      Id = default;
      Description = description;
   }

   public int Id { get; }

   public string Description { get; }
}

public class AddressEntity : IAuditableEntity {
   public AddressEntity() {
      Id = default;
   }

   public int Id { get; }

   public int CustomerId { get; set; }

   public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }

   public string Line1 { get; set; }

   public string Line2 { get; set; }

   public string Line3 { get; set; }

   public string Province { get; set; }

   public string PostalCode { get; set; }

   public int CountryId { get; set; }

   public AddressTypeEntity AddressType { get; }

   public CountryEntity Country { get; }
}

public class AddressTypeEntity {
   public AddressTypeEntity(string description) {
      Id = default;
      Description = description;
   }

   public int Id { get; }

   public string Description { get; }
}

public class CountryEntity {
   public CountryEntity(int numericCode, string alpha2Code, string alpha3Code, string englishName, string frenchName) {
      NumericCode = numericCode;
      Alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
      Alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
      EnglishName = englishName;
      FrenchName = frenchName;
   }

   public int NumericCode { get; }

   public string Alpha2Code { get; }

   public string Alpha3Code { get; }

   public string EnglishName { get; }

   public string FrenchName { get; }
}
```

Following are the corresponding DTO classes:

```
public class CustomerWithAddressDTO {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public string CustomerType { get; set; }

   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

   public bool IsPremierCustomer { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<AddressDTO> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDTO {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string AddressType { get; set; }

   public string Line1 { get; set; }

   public string Line2 { get; set; }

   public string Line3 { get; set; }

   public string Province { get; set; }

   public string PostalCode { get; set; }

   public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I have mapping defined as follows:

```
public class CustomerWithAddressProfile : Profile {
   public CustomerWithAddressProfile() {
      CreateMap<AddressEntity, AddressDTO>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.AddressType, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.AddressType.Description))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Country, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Country.Alpha3Code));

      CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerWithAddressDTO>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerType, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.CustomerType.Description))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Addresses, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Addresses));
   }
}
```

In my code, I fetch the customers including addresses from database and map as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerWithAddressDTO>> GetAllCustomers() {   
   var customers = _customerWithAddressRepository.FindAll();
   var customerDTOs = _mapper.Map<ICollection<CustomerEntity>, IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>>(customers);

   return Ok(customerDTOs);
}
```

The customers are getting populated (mapped) correctly. But the nested addresses are never getting populated. I have searched for a solution but still no luck. Does anyone has any thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `customers` you can access the addresses? after `_customerWithAddressRepository.FindAll();`

Comment: Yes. And I got it working by changing the code as follows:

var customerDTOs = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CustomerWithAddressDTO>>(customers);

Thanks (it's just one of those days).